# How Do I Run Multiple Interactive Shells From One Script?

Tags: shell-script, konsole

After building my code I have to run 3 java processes from different directories.

Each of these has processes has an interactive console so I need to open them in new windows or new tabs in konsole.

What I do manually is:

```
cd build
cd dir1
java -jar my.jar
#New tab
cd ../dir2
java -jar my.jar
#New tab
cd ../dir3
java -jar my.jar
```

After a while it gets quite tedious and repetitive.

How can do this from a script? I can't just use the commands by themselves because I need a new konsole tab or window for each process.

Comment: Do you actually care about the command line output? If you don't, just run it in the background.

Comment: "Each of these has processes has an interactive console" - so yes of course I care about the command output!

Comment: Did you consider running `konsole -e java -jar my.jar` multiple times?